# Maximal bounds for a variable

Tags: number-theory

> If $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers, then there are integers $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $$1 = px_0+qy_0.$$ Determine the maximum value of $b-a$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers with the following property:
>
> If $a \leq t \leq b$, and $t$ is an integer, then there are integers $x$ and $y$ with $0 \leq x \leq q-1$ and $0 \leq y \leq p-1$ such that $t = px + qy$.

I am not sure why they mention "there are integers $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $1 = px_0+qy_0$." I made a list of the values for various such  expressions and discovered they are symmetric, but I am not sure how to count the number of numbers in the segment with consecutive numbers.

**Does anyone see a pattern in the below that could lead us to answer the question?**

$2x+3y: 0,\underbrace{2,3,4,5}_{5-2=3},7$

$2x+5y: 0,2,\underbrace{4,5,6,7,8,9}_{9-4=5},11,13$

$2x+7y: 0,2,4,\underbrace{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}_{13-6=7},15,17,19$

$3x+5y: 0,3,5,6,\underbrace{8,9,10,11,12,13,14}_{14-8=6},16,17,19,22$

$3x+7y: 0,3,6,7,9,10,\underbrace{12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}_{20-12=8},22,23,25,26,29,32$

$3x+11y: 0,3,6,9,11,12,15,17,18,\underbrace{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32}_{32-20=12},34,35,37,38,40,41,43,46,49,52$

Comment: Based on this very limited number of cases, it holds that $b-a=p+q-2$. No idea if that continues on, though... I would guess it's more complicated than that!

Comment: @DivergentQueries How would we prove that $b-a=p+q-2$?

Comment: I would check whether that pattern holds for more cases before trying to prove it; my intuition says it won't, but it is often wrong.

Comment: @DivergentQueries It is true, though.

Comment: How many pairs $(p,q)$ have you tested it with?

Comment: @DivergentQueries Technically infinitely many. It always holds if one of the primes is $2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41423/discussion-between-divergent-queries-and-puzzled417).

Comment: @ErickWong Can you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Some observations:** Since we know $1=px_0+qy_0$ has a solution $(x_0, y_0)$, then given an arbitrary equation $t=px+qy$ we can produce $t+1=p(x+x_0)+q(y+y_0)$. This means that, starting with $0=0p+0q$, we have $n=p(nx_0)+q(ny_0)$.

Also consider that $p(q)+q(-p)=0$, so $t=px+qy=p(x+q)+q(y-p)$. This gives us the means to bring solutions into an acceptable range.

Comment: Right, so we just have to worry about $nx_0 > q-1, nq_0 > p-1$ and $nx_0 < 0$ and $ny_0 < 0$. Could we prove there is a solution if and only if $nx_0 < 0$ and $ny_0 > p-1$ or $nx_0 > q-1$ and $ny_0 < 0$?